# Returning objects implementing interfaces

Tags: java

I have a given set of interfaces, and I have to implement them.
The interfaces are the following:

```
package com.something.interfaces;
public interface A {
    void foo();
    Set<B> bar();
}

package com.something.interfaces;
public interface B {
    void foobar();
}
```

And my implementations are the following:

```
package com.something.implementations;
public class A implements com.something.interfaces.A {
    @Override 
    public void foo(){
        //Something
    }

    @Override
    public Set<com.something.interfaces.B> bar(){
        Set<com.something.implementations.B> something = new HashSet<com.something.implementations.B>();
        //...
        return something;
    }
}

package com.something.implementations;
public class B implements com.something.interfaces.B {
    @override
    public void foobar(){
        //Something
    }
}
```

The problem is in the method bar() of the implemented class. It gives me the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Set<com.something.interfaces.B> to java.util.Set<com.something.implementations.B>
```

I am 100% sure that the signature are respected, I tried just leaving the auto generated stubs to check. Maybe there is something I am missing on the theory, but how can I implement the method if this does not work?

Thanks

**EDIT**
As this question has been marked as a possible duplicate, I will explain the difference with it.

That was a generic question, I have a really specific problem here. The interfaces are not accessible by me, because I am writing code that will be submitted and autograded using original interfaces, I won't submit any modifications.

Knowing what that question pointed out does not help me understand how to escape from this situation, because given these interfaces, I need to return my implemented versions of them, and that question really gave me no clue on how to do that.

**EDIT2**

In the comments, it has been pointed out that my requirements are not clear. I'll try to clarify.

I can't change the interfaces, I need to be sure that this is a problem of interfaces and that there is not a workaround for this. If this is the case, I will try to reason with my professor.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that question, it was useful for learning purposes, but I explained in the EDIT what is missing from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your implementation of the `bar()` method to this:

```
@Override
public Set<com.something.interfaces.B> bar(){
    Set<com.something.interfaces.B> something = new HashSet<com.something.interfaces.B>();
    //...
    return something;
}
```

You can fill the Set in `something` with any object which implements the `com.something.interfaces.B` interface, including your implementation class `com.something.implementations.B`.

Answer (score -2):

Change your interface A like this:

```
public interface A {
    void foo();
    Set<com.something.interfaces.B> bar();
}
```

Change the names of your interfaces or your implementations to avoid confusion

Comment: The interface is not accessible to me.

Comment: why not if it is on the same package as interface A ?  import your interface, the problem is that method is taken the class instead of the interface, or try to change the name , your class should not have the same name as your interface, try with   BImpl,  AImpl .